# how do I pass arguments to construct from a phpspec?

Tags: php, phpspec

if I have

```
function let(Foo bar)
{
    $this->beConstructedWith($bar);
}
```

it works great, but how do I actually pass arguments to the construct? It only works if I have a construct with no arguments passed to it, and use setters after construction. Isn't there a way to construct normally?

I've tried looking this up but all examples use constructs without arguments. Thanks.

Comment: oops, I missed the $ on bar.

Comment: You can always edit your own question

Comment: Maybe useful: **[PhpSpec: 'Let' : If you need to pass the object into the constructor instead of a method then you can do it like this...](http://phpspec.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/let-and-letgo.html)**

Comment: By calling $this->beConstructedWith($bar); you're telling phpspec to pass $bar as a constructor argument.

Answer (score 2):

You are already passing an arguement to your constructor by using $this->beConstrutedWith($bar)

The first example that you run, using a method from your SUT, will cause the constructor of the class to be called with $bar:

```
class Baz 
{
   public function __construct(Foo $bar)
   {
   }
}
```

Here is the most up-to-date documenation on let()
http://phpspec.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/construction.html#using-the-constructor:

```
namespace spec;

use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Markdown\Writer;

class MarkdownSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_outputs_converted_text(Writer $writer)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($writer);
        $writer->writeText("<p>Hi, there</p>")->shouldBeCalled();

        $this->outputHtml("Hi, there");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are referencing documentation, please put the relevant portions of the documentation into your answer.  The link is only viable as part of the answer until it changes.